# Change numbering of chemical equations - chemmacros

Tags: chemmacros

I am using `chemmacros` to write chemical reactions, and want to change the way they are numbered from  {1},{2},{3}.. to [R1],[R2],[R3].

I have tried what is on the package (page 43) but it doesn't work, maybe because my version is old (4.6).
Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside
]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %relacionado al input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{reactions}
A + B &<=> C + clus \label{reaccio4} \\
D + clus &<=> F + H \label{reaccionRef3}\\
A + B + D &<=> F + G + H  \label{reaccion_neta3}
\end{reactions}
\end{document}
```

It produces:

[image]

Any help?

Comment: Your code is not compilable  for me: there's a problem with the labels. Without labels, I know how to do it.

Comment: mm @Bernard that is strange, I need the labels and it is in the example of the package also..

Comment: I have an error message – `\chemformula` seems to be an unknown command (it appears in the `.aux` file, due to the labels).

Comment: That is really strange, I checked and it is compiling  in Texmaker @Bernard.

Comment: Not with this very code: I had  to add `\chemsetup{modules=all}`  to make it accept the `reactions` environment and compile without error if I commented the labels.

Comment: @Bernard but labels should work, as they are on page 43 of `chemmacros` package documentation..; I need them, it is not to bother you..I think it must be a problem of versions. As I wrote on the post, my version is 4.6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65321/discussion-between-hernan-miraola-and-bernard).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65322/discussion-between-hernan-miraola-and-bernard).

Comment: the simplest solution is (i) update you `chemmacros` package to recent version (v5.8b), (ii) set up your equations as is described in package manual on bottom of page 43.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39791558#39791558

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enclose the `\label{...}` in `"..."`:

```
\begin{reactions}
  A + B &<=> C + clus "\label{reaccio4}" \\
  D + clus &<=> F + H "\label{reaccionRef3}" \\
  A + B + D &<=> F + G + H  "\label{reaccion_neta3}"
\end{reactions}
```

With versions older than v5.0 of `chemmacros` use

```
\renewtagform{reaction}{[R}{]}
```

in order to change the tag form of the reaction tags.